# Dynamic Related List - Single is missing related lists

Tags: lightning, page-layout

I'm adding a Dynamic related list - single to the case page. When using Industries, a field on the Application object is added called ApplicationCase which links to case. In the standard page layouts this means you can add a 'Applications' related list to the page layout, however when using a Dynamic related list on the Lightning page editor, the Application object is not selectable from the 'Related List' picklist.

[image]

[image]
I've noticed there a number of other items missing from this as well. Why could this be?

Answer (score 1):

There's no *easy* way for someone to know which object does or does not support being a dynamic related list - but, the quickest test would be checking that the entity itself (in your case, `IndividualApplication`) supports dynamic forms for its own record page (you can test in Lightning app builder).

**As of Spring '24, `IndividualApplication` doesn't support dynamic forms which is why it's related list on Case is not available for Dynamic Related List - Single**. However (safe harbor), I can see internally that this is planned to change in Summer '24.

[image]

[image]

*I work at Salesforce, not on the team necessarily that owns IndividualApplication but on a cloud that leverages that entity as well*

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the insight!